# Sanitise PHP variable and send to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to make an instant search form, at this moment the list is static however I want to make it dynamic so that results that are pulled from a database are sent to the JS script and sanitised in the appropriate format so that results are generated dynamically.

AngularJS:

```
    angular.module('sortApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.sortType     = 'name'; // set the default sort type
  $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
  $scope.searchFish   = '';     // set the default search/filter term

  // create the list of people
  $scope.names = [
    { name: '' },


  ];

});
```

My PHP and HTML:

```
    $sql = "SELECT id, first_name, last_name from library";

    $results = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
            $id=$row["id"];
            $first_name=$row["first_name"];
            $last_name=$row["last_name"];

            echo htmlentities(json_encode($first_name->names));
    }

    ?>

  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
            Name
            <span ng-show="sortType == 'name' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
            <span ng-show="sortType == 'name' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'team'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
          Team
            <span ng-show="sortType == 'team' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
            <span ng-show="sortType == 'team' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="schedular in names | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchname">
        <td>{{ schedular.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ schedular.team }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

So as soon as the page is opened, a query is looped based on my SQL code, the results from the SQL query need to be sent to the AngularJS form and populated in:

```
$scope.names = [
    { name: '' },

  ];

});
```

Statically this is how the AngularJS looks like:

```
angular.module('sortApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.sortType     = 'name'; // set the default sort type
  $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
  $scope.searchFish   = '';     // set the default search/filter term

  // create the list of people
  $scope.names = [
    { name: 'John Smith' },


  ];

});
```

But I want the name 'John Smith' to be pulled dynamically and sent to the AngularJS. How do I send dynamically generated PHP variables to AngularJS and make sure they are sanitised properly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual problem or question?

Comment: How do I pass the dynamically generated results stored in the $first_name and $last_name variables to be shown in the 'name' in the AngularJS so that it's sanitise properly?